# Perform asynchronous actions semi-synchronously in Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have the following code:

```
   * Fetch stats from api
   */
  fetchStats() {
    this._isFetching = true;
    // fetch stats after building url and replacing invalid characters
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      await API.fetchStats(this.rsn)
        .then(jres => {
          this.skills = jres.main.skills;
          this._isFetching = false;
          resolve('success');
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          console.log('error retreiving stats');
          this._isFetching = false;
          reject('Failed to retreive stats');
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this._isFetching = false;
        });
    });
  }
```

I thought making it async with await would make it wait until it got the response before continuing. Returning the promise is something I added in testing to see if I could make it synchronous.

Then my code that consumes this method:

```
memberCollection.forEach(async el => {
        await el.player.fetchStats()
        .then(() => {
          console.log(`Refreshed ${el.player.rsn}'s account`);
        })
        .catch(console.log(`Failed to refresh ${el.player.rsn}'s account`));
});
```

My thinking was that it would wait till it got a response then `console.log` either a successful refresh or a failed refresh. What I am instead seeing is a whole bunch of "success" messages followed by a string of failed messages indicating that it is running both the then and the catch message in the foreach. Does anyone know how I can make this work.

My issue is that Axios keeps timing out (my speculation is that it is due to the number of requests being sent off and the fact that there is a 5-10sec delay as it pulls from the db), if I navigate to the API URL manually it works as well as if I just do one member (as opposed to forEach) it works fine. So I'm trying to limit the number of requests fired off at once. I have tried setting my axios timeout to 10, 20, and 60 seconds, but it made no improvement.

Solution code:

```
const asyncForEach = async (arr, cb) => {
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    let el = arr[i];
    try {
      let res = await cb(el);
    } catch (err) { console.log(err) };

    if(el.player && el.player.rsn) console.log(`Processed ${el.player.rsn}`);
  }
  console.log('done processing in asyncForEach');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not linked to axios but to `async await`.

consider

```
function slow(i){
    return new Promise((ok,ko)=>{
        return setTimeout(_=>ok(i), 1000)
    })
}
async function asyncForEach(arr, cb){
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; ++i){
        let el = arr[i];
        let res = await cb(el);
        console.log('async', res, new Date)
    }
}

/*
#foreach does not wait, but async and reduce are spaced by one second
foreach 4 2019-10-14T13:43:47.059Z
foreach 5 2019-10-14T13:43:47.071Z
foreach 6 2019-10-14T13:43:47.071Z
async 1 2019-10-14T13:43:47.071Z
async 2 2019-10-14T13:43:48.073Z
async 3 2019-10-14T13:43:49.074Z
reduce 7 2019-10-14T13:43:50.076Z
reduce 8 2019-10-14T13:43:51.078Z
reduce 9 2019-10-14T13:43:52.080Z
*/ 
async function main(){

    await [4,5,6].forEach(async el=>{
        let res = await slow(el);
        console.log('foreach', res, new Date)
    })
    await asyncForEach([1,2,3], slow);

    await [7,8,9].reduce((acc, el)=>acc.then(async _=>{
        let res = await slow(el);
        console.log('reduce', res, new Date);
        return;
    }), Promise.resolve())
}
main();
```

As you can see from timestamps, `forEach` does not wait for `slow` to finish
however, `asyncForEach` in its iteration **does** wait

What you may want to do is either

- write a for loop as done with `asyncForEach`
- use standard promises (stacking them):

  ```
  [1,2,3].reduce((acc, el)=>acc.then(_=>{
      return slow(el);
  }), Promise.resolve())
  ```

Comment: That works perfectly. I will post my code for reference but creating the `asyncForEach` utility function seems to have resolved it.